# Setting Page Visibility for WooCommerce Default Page Doesn't Work

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

On my site, I don't use the chop page or the cart page of WooCommerce as I directly send people to the checkout page. So, I tried to set the page visibility to "Private" but even after that anyone with the shop URL can visit the shop page and it is showing perfectly fine.

[image: Private Shop Page]

Whereas I created a normal test page and made it Private and when I am checking it from an incognito window it is giving 404. Exactly what I want. But this same thing is not working for WooCommerce default pages.

Does anyone know why? I have already tried all the troubleshooting steps but no result. I got no clue why the WooCommerce default pages are not respective the WordPress settings.

Answer (score 0):

As per the answer here on the [WooCommerce WordPress.org Support Forum](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/setting-page-visibility-for-woocommerce-default-page-doesnt-work/#post-12787237):

> The shop **“page”** isn’t actually a WordPress page. It’s an archive of all the products on the store. Because of that, it doesn’t behave like a typical WordPress page.
>
> You could not assign a page to be the shop. Here’s how to do that:
>
> [image: select shop page]
>
> - Go to WooCommerce > Settings > Products.
> - At the top in the drop-down for Shop page, clear the field.
> - Save your changes.